# Decimal indexing a function defined inside a loop

Tags: matrix

I have the matrix M initialized to be an empty 3x3 matrix. 
I want to run a loop which fills the diagonal with a decimal value, k. 
I also want to make it so I can see the matrix M for each value of k, and find the Eigenvalues of M. Here is an example:

```
k = -.5; While[k < .51, Do[Do[If[i == j, M[[i, j]] = k(*enters diagonal terms*)],{i, 1, 3, 1}], (*loops i*){j, 1, 3, 1} ];(*loops j*)T[[k]] = M;En[[k]] = Eigenvalues[M];(*store eigenvalues*)k = k + .01](*loops k from -.5 to .5 in steps of .01*)
```

I am getting an error with my current code as Mathematica doesn't like the decimal indices, and I am not sure how to change it integer and convert k for the diagonal terms correctly.

Comment: I think I answered my own question: use T[[Round[k*100 + 50]]] = M;
En[[Round[k*100 + 50]]] = Eigenvalues[M].

Comment: If someone has a better solution I would definitely appreciate the insight though

Answer (score 1):

use T[[Round[k*100 + 50]]] = M; En[[Round[k*100 + 50]]] = Eigenvalues[M]